# Why doesn't adding a number to Double.MaxValue makes it Double.PositiveInfinity?

Tags: c#

In [Double.PositiveInfinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) docs it's written that:

> This constant is returned when the result of an operation is greater than MaxValue.

However, when I try to add a number to maximum value of `double`, it doesn't return `infinity`. I've tried running this:

```
double maxVal = Double.MaxValue;
maxVal = maxVal + 10000000000000000000;
Console.WriteLine(maxVal + " " + Double.IsInfinity(maxVal)); //prints 1.79769313486232E+308 False
```

Why is it happening? Why isn't it showing `maxVal` as `infinity`?

[Here is a working fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s5KyMe)

Comment: Value `10000000000000000000` just to small to make any difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because the number that you are adding is *way* too small to make a dent on the `Double.MaxValue` value.

The precision of a `double` is about 15 digits, so you need a number that is at least `1e292` for it to be large enough to make a difference.

That would be `10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` written out.

Comment: But why doesn't it overflow? You keep adding numbers to double and it stays at Double.MaxValue? I just added `8000000000000000000` to `MaxValue` 100000 times in a loop, and it's still `MaxValue`.

Comment: @MillieSmith you added 8E+23. That would be about the 285th symbol after the dot for the MaxValue. However, the length of the mantissa in Double is only 15 symbols. Adding 8E+23 didn't actually change the number.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov Yeah, but I don't understand why they made it that way. I just did `max += 1e292`, and now `Double.IsInfinity` returns true. It does not work with `1e291`. I would expect the behavior to be defined differently.

Comment: This is a good answer @MillieSmith try the following after adding  8000000000000000000 to maxVal, Console.WriteLine(maxVal == double.MaxValue); and notice that maxVal == Double.MaxValue returns true, this is because of the way arithmetic for doubles works. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point.

Comment: @MillieSmith: The result is rounded to fit the 15 digits after the calculation, so if for example `1.797693134862315701e308` (`MaxValue + 1e290`) is larger than `MaxValue`, after rounding it's still equal to `MaxValue`. The CPU uses a few digits more internally to do the calculation, but even a value like `1e289` is so small that it will be zero when brought into the same range as `MaxValue`.

Comment: But then this is a lack of documentation, it clearly states that _" Double.PositiveInfinity  is returned when the result of an operation is greater than MaxValue"_ which is the case for `double.MaxValue+1`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The result of `double.MaxValue + 1` is actually `double.MaxValue`. The computer can't use an infinite precision when adding the numbers, so the `1` disappears when it is brought into the same range as `double.MaxValue`. Another example of this would be `1 + 1e-20`, where the result is `1`. If you try to represent `1.00000000000000000001` as a `double` you will get `1` as that last decimal falls outside the precision of the `double`.

Answer (score 0):

- By definition, [IsInfinity(double d)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs) returns true when

`(*(long*)(&d) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) == 0x7FF0000000000000;`

When you substitute it in your example, then you will see that `double.MaxValue` which value is `1.7976931348623157E+308` + `10000000000000000000` is still smallest than `0x7FF0000000000000` after conversion.

- Why does it return `double.MaxValue`, because, as per math definition, `X+z=X` for very greater values of X and smallest of z.