# Exceeding double max value

Tags: c#, .net

I would like you to consider both math operations:

a) if we add:

```
double maxValue = double.MaxValue + 5; //result: double.MaxValue
```

b) if we add:

```
double infinity = double.MaxValue + double.MaxValue; //result: infinity
```

Why do not we get infinite value in both cases?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29263015/why-doesnt-adding-a-number-to-double-maxvalue-makes-it-double-positiveinfinity

Comment: You need to add value that is close to difference between MaxValue and "previous representable value" for MaxValue.